# python wrap list and convert type in beautiful soup

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

Following is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen  # b_soup_1.py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Treasury Yield Curve web site, known to be HTML code
html = urlopen('https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/'
               'data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/'
               'TextView.aspx?data=yieldYear&year=2018')

# create the BeautifulSoup object (BeautifulSoup Yield Curve)
bsyc = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "lxml")

# save it to a file that we can edit
#fout = open('bsyc_temp.txt', 'wt', encoding='utf-8')

#fout.write(str(bsyc))

#fout.close()

# so get a list of all table tags
table_list = bsyc.findAll('table')


# to findAll as a dictionary attribute
tc_table_list = bsyc.findAll('table',
                      { "class" : "t-chart" } )

# only 1 t-chart table, so grab it
tc_table = tc_table_list[0]
# what are this table's components/children?
# tag tr means table row, containing table data
# what are the children of those rows?
# we have found the table data!
# just get the contents of each cell
print('\nthe contents of the children of the t-chart table:')
daily_yield_curves_temp = []
daily_yield_curves = []
for c in tc_table.children:
    for r in c.children:
        for i in r.contents:
            daily_yield_curves_temp.append(i)
for x in range(len(daily_yield_curves_temp) // 12):
    daily_yield_curves.append(daily_yield_curves_temp[12 * x : 12 * x + 12])

print(daily_yield_curves)
```

the output is:

> [['Date', '1 mo', '3 mo', '6 mo', '1 yr', '2 yr', '3 yr', '5 yr', '7
>   yr', '10 yr', '20 yr', '30 yr'], ['01/02/18', '1.29', '1.44', '1.61',
>   '1.83', '1.92', '2.01', '2.25', '2.38', '2.46', '2.64', '2.81'],
>   ['01/03/18', '1.29', '1.41', '1.59', '1.81', '1.94', '2.02', '2.25',
>   '2.37', '2.44', '2.62', '2.78'], ['01/04/18', '1.28', '1.41', '1.60',
>   '1.82', '1.96', '2.05', '2.27', '2.38', '2.46', '2.62', '2.79'],.....]

**However, I want to make the output looks like this:**

```
daily_yield_curves = [
        [ … header list … ],
        [ … first data list … ],
        …
        [ … final data list … ]
    ]
```

> ['Date', '1 mo', '3 mo', '6 mo', '1 yr', '2 yr', '3 yr',
>            '5 yr', '7 yr', '10 yr', '20 yr', '30 yr']

Following that should be a list for each data row. Convert each interest rate value from a string to a float:

> ['01/02/18', 1.29, 1.44, 1.61, 1.83, 1.92, 2.01,
>             2.25, 2.38, 2.46, 2.64, 2.81] ... ['09/14/18', 2.02, 2.16, 2.33, 2.56, 2.78, 2.85,
>             2.90, 2.96, 2.99, 3.07, 3.13]

**Please help me how to change it**

Comment: why dont you traverse the list...convert the whole thing into a df if you want...just take the first element of the list as the header for your df and all the rest as the data

Comment: Can you tell more detail about how to change the data into float type?

Comment: oh there are many ways..one is to just do dataframe.columnname = dataframe.columnname.astype(float)..